# Why ffmpeg error while trying to play live stream on a defined output device rather than on the default one?

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, ffmpeg

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. The `aplay -L` command produces the following output.

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: USB [Jabra SPEAK 510 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

When I play live audio stream produced by an ip camera through the default output audio device using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://operator:operator@10.10.210.2/axis-media/media.amp?audio=1 -f alsa default
```

it works fine.

But when I try to play it in a defined audio output device as the following:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://operator:operator@10.10.210.2/axis-media/media.amp?audio=1 -f alsa hw:0,0
```

I get the error:

```
cannot open audio device hw:0,0 (Device or resource busy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Input/output error
```

When I try another device:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://operator:operator@10.10.210.2/axis-media/media.amp?audio=1 -f alsa hw:2,0
```

This time again I get error but a slightly different one:

```
cannot set channel count to 1 (Invalid argument)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Input/output error
```

I read the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#toc-alsa), but couldn't manage to solved. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.